# Os.path.getsize goes back to the folder of .py file in a for loop

Tags: python, os.path

I have trying to do a for loop to get the file size of all the files in a folder I have. The code looks like this:

```
import os, sys
location = "/Users/username/Documents/Filmer"

for folder, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(location):

    for filename in filenames:
        print(os.path.getsize(os.path.abspath(filename)))
```

I have tried to use it without the absolute path, and with it as well. It only seems to get the size for two files before I get the error:

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
>   '/Users/username/Google
>   Drive/Data/Python/ATBSWP/Projekt/Family.Guy.2009.DVDRip.H264-BONE.mp4'

which refers to the folder in which the .py file is located, which is a completely different directory than the one the the os.walk() is in. Why does it go back to that folder? I am using the absolute path on all files in the loop so I feel like it shouldnt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
for root, subfolders, filenames in os.walk(location):
    for filename in filenames:
        print(os.path.getsize(os.path.join(root, filename)))
```

The first arg returned by `os.walk` is actually the root (complete path).